# This question is downvoted but it has many answers which carry upvotes

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have a question about my Law Stack Exchange post: [Can a country refuse to enforce international law even if it does not violate existing law?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/58177/can-a-country-refuse-to-enforce-international-law-even-if-it-does-not-violate-ex)

Why did this question get downvotes when it was well-answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speculate, since I'm not one of the people that downvoted it...but I'll give it a shot. My guess is that it was downvoted for a couple reasons:

The question in the title is somewhat unclear: it's not totally clear what you mean by "if it does not violate existing law."  The phrasing makes it sound like you're saying the *law* doesn't violate existing law, which doesn't really make sense.  A better title might be something like "Can a country refuse to enforce another country's laws forbidding conduct that is legal under the country's own laws?".

This lack of clarity is reinforced by a few comments mentioning that they found it unclear and asking clarifying questions, as well as a pending suggested edit trying to rephrase the title (you should either accept or reject it).

It's also somewhat of an unrealistic hypothetical.  No country would ever make a law demanding a $1 billion payment for the mere act of making a website accessible to its citizens, residents, or anyone within the borders of the country.  Compliance with such a law would be more or less impossible.  A more realistic hypothetical might have fared better.

Comment: I will keep the points in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the aforementioned unnecessarily ridiculous nature of the statute and the unclarity of the question as asked, this is also a generally-asked-and-answered question: does every nation have to enforce the laws of every other nation (we've had a thousand variants of that question)? Tossing in the option to go to war is legal fantasy and irrelevant, but your question about treaties should have given you a start at self-answering the question (what kind of treaty?; why does it matter if there is a treaty?).